# Не загружаются изображения PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside

Все компилируется, файлы ресурсов переработаны в файлы .py Картинки просто нету и всё. Никаких ошибок компилятор питона тоже не выдает. Мне нужно сказать почему изображения нету и, что сделать чтобы оно появилось. Вот исходники https://drive.google.com/file/d/12wlsC50NWmoA4qvQX0rmr4lJFSncNywd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Пути правильные?

Comment: @peterAlexander Chernin Да

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы упомянули `PyQt5`, а я им пользуюсь, то проделано следующее:

- конвертирую ваш `ui.ui` в `ui.py`:
  `pyuic5.exe ui.ui -o ui.py -x`

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1024, 600)
        Form.setMouseTracking(False)
        Form.setToolTip("")
        Form.setStyleSheet("#Form{\n"
"  background-image: url(:/new/prefix1/img/fon.png);\n"
"}")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 87, 581))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("#pushButton_5{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton_5:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("#pushButton_4{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton_4:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("#pushButton{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("#pushButton_3{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton_3:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("#pushButton_2{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton_2:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_6.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("#pushButton_6{\n"
" text-align:center; \n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" border:5px solid  #875ba6; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#1c2241; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton#pushButton_6:hover{\n"
" padding:18px 12px; \n"
" border:5px solid #72398a; \n"
" border-radius: 16px; \n"
" font:21px \"Arial Black\", Gadget, sans-serif; \n"
" font-weight:bold; \n"
" color:#875ba6; \n"
" background:#d5b9ea; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButton, self.pushButton_3)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButton_3, self.pushButton_2)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButton_2, self.pushButton_4)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButton_4, self.pushButton_5)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.pushButton_5, self.pushButton_6)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Smart Energy"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Shi"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Use"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Exit"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Set"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Gen"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Com"))


import img_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

- запускаю `ui.py`:
  `python ui.py`
- **все работает !**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаком с `pyside-uic`, но предполагаю, что это должно быть аналогично `pyuic5.exe`.

Предлагаю попробовать конвертацию без путей, так:
    `pyside-uic ui.ui -o ui.py -x`

Запустите: `python ui.py`
Напишите что получилось.

Comment: @peterS. Nick я не нашел pyuic5.exe есть только bat который выдает ошибку. У меня при перегонке из ui в py при помощь Pyside ругается на вот такую строку в коде каждой кнопки и её приходится удалять. self.pushButton_4.setTabletTracking(False) Я уже начал на голом PyQt5 писать всё с нуля не используя этот QT Designer

Comment: @ДаниилРассадкин я же вам уже писал установите `pip install pyqt5-tools` читать здесь https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Comment: У меня он установлен но pyuic.exe там нету

Comment: @ДаниилРассадкин  `...\Python\Scripts\pyuic5.exe`

Comment: Нету и все)  Скачать отдельно его нельзя?

Comment: Вы есть в ВК? Мне там удобнее будет спрашивать

Comment: @ДаниилРассадкин почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+pyuic5  и  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+pyuic5

Comment: Я уже на чистом PyQT писать стал. Полностью всё сам с нуля.